# cant get all rows with date pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

i seacrching around dataframe to get all texts from date, i dont know where i fail

```
 def date_extract(start, end):
  date_start = datetime.strptime(start, '%Y/%m/%d')
  date_end  = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y/%m/%d')
  all =pd.DataFrame()
  while date_start<=date_end:
    date_start += timedelta(days=1)
    pd.concat([df[df['date'].str.contains(datetime.strftime(date_start, '%Y/%m/%d')),all]])
  return all
```

And i  get this error

```
TypeError: '(0         False
1         False
2         False
3         False
4         False
          ...  
165532    False
165533    False
165534    False
165535    False
165536    False
Name: date, Length: 165537, dtype: bool, Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [])' is an invalid key
```

Comment: What is `df` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes at this line:

```
pd.concat([df[df['date'].str.contains(datetime.strftime(date_start, '%Y/%m/%d')),all]])
```

First, you have to move one of the square brackets at the end to before the last comma.
Second, you need to assign that value to the variable "all" again to be able to return the result at the end of the loop.

It should be like this:

```
all = pd.concat([df[df['date'].str.contains(datetime.strftime(date_start, '%Y/%m/%d'))],all])
```

Just change that line and it should work as expected. It would be better if you could give example of your variables such as df in which you are searching through. I suspect there might be better ways to achieve that.

Comment: Tottaly no, its sends errr thats all is list, i changed it it to Dataframe but it didnt work( TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'type'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid